# Could I let webpack not minify the js code?

Tags: javascript, webpack

webpack4 by default will minify js code, is there any option I ould generate bundle.js without minifying?

Comment: IIRC webpack will only minify if it is being ran in production mode.

Comment: the default is production mode? since I don't specify mode

Comment: BTW, how to specify mode?

Comment: for windows it's doing something like `set NODE_ENV=development` or something, I honestly don't remember I work largely in containers.

Answer (score 6):

In short: of course. Just set `minimize` property to `false` in your config.

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  }
};
```

[Here's](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimization-minimize) documentation that can describes it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can as stated in the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/) and under [optimization](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/)..

In optimization just set minimize to false:

```
optimization: {
 minimize: false
}
```

EDIT: already answered - this SO-community is lightning fast.. ;)